# Scipy - How to load an image from memory into scipy.misc.imread?

Tags: python, scipy

I am trying to make a REST API on top of Scipy.  I need to use the function scipy.misc.imread(file, 'RGB') to load an image.  However, I don't want to save it to disk because I already have it loaded in memory - I just want to load it from in-memory.

How can I do this?

Comment: FYI: `scipy.misc.imread` is deprecated in SciPy 1.0.0, and [will be removed in 1.2.0.](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imread.html)

Comment: @Piinthesky In this case am working with an OSS project that uses it so semi-stuck with it.  So do you know of a way to load from memory?

Comment: Well... how is it stored in memory? Why load something to memory if it's already in memory (or more precise: why do you want to use a file-targeted load-func for non-file based sources)?

Comment: hi @Abr can you put code which has loaded it in memory ... and code what you want to do now... are they(codes) in different modules / functions / class ?